# Is there a way to register a mobile ( Android / iOS) client in ADFS 2019?

Tags: adfs, adfs4.0

Is it possible to use ADFS SSO with a mobile client? And If so, how to register one? 
Or if there is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft speak, a mobile client is called a "Native client".

There are some samples for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/msal/adfs-msal-native-app-web-api).

You can expand the menu on the left to see other examples.

These use the MSAL libraries. There are MSAL samples for both iOS and Android.

The best place to look is the [quick starts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-android) for the Microsoft Identity Platform.

Again, you can expand the menu on the left to see other examples.

These are for Azure AD but you can use the ADFS samples to see what to change.